# Beautifulsoup can't find div in html code after comment

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a scraping code using python and Beautifulsoup.

I am trying to scrape the info contained in the second `<div class="table_container" id="div_shot-chart">`, which is anticipated by an exact copy that is commented out with `<!-- ... -->`, as can be seen from the code sample below. For reference you can find the HTML code [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdursh01/shooting/2001).

```
<div id="all_shot-chart" class="table_wrapper">

<div class="section_heading assoc_shot-chart" id="shot-chart_sh">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="shot-chart_link" data-label="Shot Chart"></span><h2>Shot Chart</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
            
</div><div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--

<div class="table_container" id="div_shot-chart">
    
    <table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" id="shot-chart" data-cols-to-freeze="0">
    <caption>Shot Chart Table</caption>
    <div id="shot-wrapper">
<div class="shot-area">
<img src="http://d2p3bygnnzw9w3.cloudfront.net/req/1/images/bbr/nbahalfcourt.png" 
     alt="nbahalfcourt" 
     >
<div style="top:166px;left:236px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 11:22 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 12 ft<br>VAN now leads 2-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
<div style="top:76px;left:72px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 9:37 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 17 ft<br>VAN now leads 9-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
<div style="top:59px;left:236px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 9:16 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 1 ft<br>VAN now leads 11-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>

… A LOT MORE OF THE SAME 'COMMENTED OUT' CODE THAT I HAVE DELETED …

</div>
</div>
<div id='shot-chart'></div>
</table>


</div>
-->

<div class="table_container" id="div_shot-chart">
    
    <table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" id="shot-chart" data-cols-to-freeze="0">
    <caption>Shot Chart Table</caption>
    <div id="shot-wrapper">
<div class="shot-area">
<img src="http://d2p3bygnnzw9w3.cloudfront.net/req/1/images/bbr/nbahalfcourt.png" 
     alt="nbahalfcourt" 
     >
<div style="top:166px;left:236px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 11:22 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 12 ft<br>VAN now leads 2-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
<div style="top:76px;left:72px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 9:37 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 17 ft<br>VAN now leads 9-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
<div style="top:59px;left:236px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 9:16 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 1 ft<br>VAN now leads 11-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
<div style="top:250px;left:236px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 7:28 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 20 ft<br>VAN now leads 15-2" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
<div style="top:206px;left:102px;" tip="Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 6:15 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 21 ft<br>VAN now leads 20-4" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>

… A LOT MORE OF THE SAME 'ACTIVE' CODE THAT I HAVE DELETED …

</div>
</div><div id="shot-chart"></div><table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table now_sortable" id="shot-chart" data-cols-to-freeze="0">
    <caption>Shot Chart Table</caption>

</table>

</div>
</div>
```

The python code I am using is

```
 div_content = soup.find('div', {'id': 'content', 'role': 'main'})
 div_shot_chart = div_content.find('div', {'id': 'all_shot-chart'})
 shot_chart = div_shot_chart.find_all('div', {'id': 'div_shot_chart'})
```

`div_content` and `div_shot_chart` successfully return the portion of code desired but `shot_chart` is always empty. My guess is that this is caused by the commented out part as the comment section is concluded with `-->`, but I am not sure. In any case I cannot seem to be able to find a solution. Could anyone help please?

Comment: If youu vote it down please let me know why. It is important that I find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is inside an HTML comment, so first locate the comment and then parse the HTML inside. BeautifulSoup will treat the contents of a comment as a string which is why you don't see it when you search for it.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests

req = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdursh01/shooting/2001")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if "div_shot-chart" in comment:
        soup_chart = BeautifulSoup(comment.string, "html.parser")
        
        for div_tip in soup_chart.find_all('div', class_="tooltip", tip=True):
            print(div_tip['tip'])
```

Giving you output starting:

```
Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 11:22 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 12 ft<br>VAN now leads 2-0
Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 9:37 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 17 ft<br>VAN now leads 9-0
Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 9:16 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 1 ft<br>VAN now leads 11-0
Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 7:28 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 20 ft<br>VAN now leads 15-2
Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 6:15 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 21 ft<br>VAN now leads 20-4
Oct 31, 2000, VAN vs SEA<br>1st Qtr, 0:00 remaining<br>Missed 3-pointer from 32 ft<br>VAN leads 34-18
```